# Is there a musical with "All Star" in it?

Tags: performance, musicals

For my school assessment I need to perform a piece, however the piece must be from a musical. Being the teenager that I am, I would like to play *All Star* by Smash Mouth. Are there any musicals that contain this song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how indulgent your teachers are, and how willing they are to stretch a point, you might argue that it was included in the movie "musical" [Shrek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Star_(song)).

Ironically, while there was an actual legitimate musical created from *Shrek*, it did not include that song.

I have to admit, I'm bemused that you're choosing for your teen-aged rebellion a song that is likely as old as you are or older.  Surely there are more recent inappropriate-for-this-assignment songs to pick...

Comment: True, but Shrek... My teacher allowed All Star!

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't appear that there are.

[All-Star has appeared in the movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_Star_(song)#In_popular_culture) *Mystery Men*, the *Shrek* series, *Digimon: the Movie*, and *Rat Race*. However none of those were really musicals, and it doesn't appear that there's a well-known musical it was ever a number in (including not in the Shrek musical).

If honest-to-gawd *movie* musicals count, you could pick your favorite Beatles number from the 34 in [Across the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Across_the_Universe_(film)#Musical_numbers). Their *Blackbird*, *Dear Prudence*, and *Let it Be* were particularly great. (However, I wouldn't even attempt their *Let it Be* unless you have a **powerful** voice to bring the ending home).

If you just want to be a perverse teenager, their version of "[Why don't we do it in the road?](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiw8rLqwJjVAhVE7yYKHaegB2AQyCkIJTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DaIG2eOtNBkQ&usg=AFQjCNGTdCf5xYfEpJWeoVrOEpvGqMgaGg)" would be a great choice.

Other promising popular rocks songs:

- *Johnny B. Goode* (from [The Buddy Holly Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_%E2%80%93_The_Buddy_Holly_Story#Song_list)).
- *Tie Your Mother Down*, *Fat Bottomed Girls*, or *Bicycle Race* (from [We Will Rock You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Will_Rock_You_(musical)#Music))
- *We're Not Gonna Take It* (from [Rock of Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_of_Ages_(musical)#Musical_numbers), with a host of other good 70's-to-80's stuff)
- *American Idiot*, *Good Riddance (Time of Your Life)*, and *Wake Me When September Ends* (from [American Idiot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Idiot_(musical)#Musical_numbers))

Comment: Ah, but has he ever heard (of) any of those songs?

Comment: Other people in my class are doing some of those songs, so it would be boring if I did them too. Luckily, my teacher allowed All Star!!

Comment: @Amorris - Grats! In that case, I presume they bought something along the lines of Chris Sunami's answer, so I'd suggest clicking the checkmark next to it. Also clicking the uparrow on it would be a nice touch.

Comment: @Amorris - Oh, and tell your teacher I said whoever picked *Fat Bottomed Girls* deserves an "A", as long as they don't completely butcher it.